# Run "While loop" in background

Tags: c++, multithreading, while-loop

I have a Credential Provider dll application in C++. Inside this dll i create a process that will write some data in a file. I need somehow to read that data from file till the value is > -1. I can not use a while loop because my dll will stop loading till the while loop will end. Can i use a separate thread to do this and to get a notification to run a function from my dll when the while loop end? How can i do this? Is there a simple way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only really practical way to achieve concurrency is using threads. Take a look at [boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler implements C++0x thread, then you can make use of it.

Read this extensive tutorial on C++0x multi-threading : [Multithreading in C++0x part 1: Starting Threads](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html)